# How to validate the input field ng-model value and display error message at the UI without refering 'ng-form' or 'form' names

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Background:**

I am trying to create a validator directive which could be placed in any input field. And this directive should validate the 'ngModel' value and then generate error messages for display at the UI.

I don't want to use an ng-form around my input field as I have noticed severe performance impacts related to using large number of ng-form elements in the page (mostly in IE browser).

**My UI page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
 <head>
   <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="angular-messages.min.js"></script>
   <script src="ngmessages.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <form name="twitter">
   <input type='email' name="twitt" ng-model="message" twitter-input required/>
 </form>

 <script type="text/ng-template" id="generic-messages">
  <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
  <div ng-message="email">This is invalid email</div>
 </script>

 </body>

</html>
```

**My Script code** ('ngmessages.js')

```
angular.module("app",['ngMessages'])
.directive('twitterInput', function($compile) {
 return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

     function valueValdate(value){              

      if(ngModel.$error.required || ngModel.$error.email){
        var e = $compile('<div ng-messages="twitter.twitt.$error"><div ng-messages-include="generic-messages"></div></div>')(scope);       

        element.after(e);
      }     
    return value;
   }

   ngModel.$parsers.push(valueValdate);  
   ngModel.$formatters.push(valueValdate); 
  }
```

};
});

**My Issues  :**

1)  At the moment the reference to the $error object is hard coded ('twitter.twitt.$error') within the code

```
 $compile('<div ng-messages="twitter.twitt.$error"><div ng-messages-include="generic-messages"></div></div>')(scope);
```

I don't know how I can make it dynamic.

2) There is no validation error displayed when the page is loaded first time. And every time you key in a value to the input field there are multiple error messages are displayed in the UI ...which is incorrect.

3) ***What is the best way to dynamically validate the input field ng-model value and display the error message at the UI. I don't want to use the 'ng-form' or 'form' name any where in my ui code as I don't want to attach my validator to any specific field. I want it all done at the directive level. ***